# IDataErrorInfo and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mvvm

I'm studying NHibernate and MVVM and came across the following problem:

Once model classes on nhibernate should be POCO objects, there is another way to implement IDataErrorInfo and INotifyPropertyChanged on model classes?

For example:

```
public class Person 
{
public virtual int ID { get; set; }
public virtual string firstName { get; set; }
public virtual string lastName { get; set; }
public virtual string phoneNumber{ get; set; }
//...
//implementation of equals and hash
//...
}
```

INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public virtual int ID { get; set; }
public virtual string firstName { get; set; }
public virtual string lastName { get; set; }
public virtual string phoneNumber{ get; set; }

public virtual string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

public virtual string LastName
    {
        get{ return lastName; }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    public virtual string PhoneNumber
    {
        get { return phoneNumber;}
        set
        {
            phone = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Phone");
        }
    }

}
#region INofityPropertyChanged members
public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
{
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
}
#endregion
```

Note that the INotifyPropertyChanged (or another interface like IDataErrorInfo) code doesn't concern the domain.

The question is: on the point of view of a good modeling, is this acceptable? 
Should I implement those interfaces on my ViewModel?

Comment: Your question is confusing. What do you think POCO means? How does this prevent you from implementing those interfaces? You should probably expand your question to describe a concrete problem - currently it's too broad.

Comment: Aren't POCO an class that contain only fields regarding the domain? When implementing those interfaces on model, am I violating this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object I think the key point is that the POCO term originates from the Java ORM world, where your entities originally had to inherit from a framework base class, bringing in a lot of functionality that made the class cumbersome to use outside that framework. As I understand it, since the interfaces you mention are irrelevant to the ORM, it can therefore be argued that the object is still POCO with regards to the ORM. And also they are interfaces, not base classes, so you control all logic.

So I don't think you must necessarily avoid these interfaces in the entities based on some theoretical rule violation.

On the other hand, this doesn't answer the question of whether it's a good idea or not. I have never had those interfaces there, but I write mostly multi-tier web based applications where they are less useful anyway. What often happens is that the view doesn't correspond to a single entity - instead a view model is useful to aggregate information from several entities, and then pass that to the view.

While the interfaces themselves are pretty basic, they are used by data binding - which means they must be on the classes used for databinding to be useful.

My suggestion is that it comes down to this: Implement them on the classes you use for databinding, providing that can be done without causing issues for anything else.